# Follow up when HR did not attend my interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, follow-up

I had an interview earlier this week, and it was supposed to be between an HR, another employee and I. Unfortunately, the HR person got caught up into an emergency and could not attend the interview, so only myself and the other employee were present at the interview. I have the HR person's contact information as well as my updated resume, which is better than the resume that I had originally provided them.

Considering that I did not meet the HR person face to face, would it be appropriate for me to email my updated resume to him, saying to him that I want to provide everyone with more information?

Comment: I just found out about this position on the last applying date so I did not have the time to perfected my resume. Is it appropriate to send the newer version thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes.

I'd send an email then follow up with a phone call a few hours later.  In the call I'd reference the email and ask what the next steps were.